# Multiple Sheets, format row 1 bold and word-wrap

Tags: excel, vba

OK, Excel VBA has defeated me again.  I suspect that when I see the answer I'll feel like an idiot.  Luckily, as I get older I'm gradually adjusting to that.  Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FormatAllSheets()
    Dim shNames()
    ReDim shNames(Worksheets.Count - 1)
    Dim shIndex As Integer
    For shIndex = 0 To UBound(shNames)
        shNames(shIndex) = Worksheets(shIndex + 1).Name
    Next shIndex

    Range("A1", "ZZ1").Select

    Sheets(shNames).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.WrapText = True
End Sub
```

Many thanks,
Tony Lima

Comment: The reason why your code is not working is because of the dreaded `Select` keyword. When you did `Range("A1", "ZZ1").Select` you had that range selected. but then you did `Sheets(shNames).Select`, which just selected the sheets in the array (sort of like holding CTRL and clicking all the sheets). You *can* multi-select ranges like you're thinking, just not that way. It would be better to iterate through the sheets, reference the range and format the cells (without using `Select`). I would always stay away from `Select` except in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, Joe.  "dreaded Select" indeed.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest method is probably as follow:

```
Sub FormatFirstRow()
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With sh.Range("A1:ZZ1")
            .Font.Bold = True
            .WrapText = True
        End With
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks.  Faster, easier, better.  Only other thing I could have asked for is in the next reply down!

Answer (score 2):

OK, Played around with this, there is a way to do it without looping but the problem is you have to do a select (Selects are my pet hate):

```
Sub BoldFirst()
    Worksheets.Select
    Rows(1).select
    Selection.Font.Bold = true
    Selection.WrapText = True
End Sub
```

I am not 100% sure but I think `Select Method` is necessary to activate the row across the multiple sheets. If you don't execute `Select` it only seems to bold in the active sheet.

It may or may not be faster than looping the sheets. It would be interesting to see if there is a performance difference.

Comment: As an old-time FORTRAN guy I'm more comfortable with looping.  But I will study your solution in the hopes that I'm still able to learn a few new tricks.  Many thanks. (And the snark directed at Select is much appreciated.)

Comment: The difference is looping will perform the same action one sheet at a time across all sheets. The method I posted will select the same range in all sheets then perform the action once, usually avoiding looping can be good but in this case because I am selecting it will negate any benefit. I didn't even notice the select in your code but here is a quick example of how not to select: Sheets("Sheet1").select    Range("A1").Select    Activecell.formula = "Hello World" can also be written as: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "Hello World" no selecting means MUCH faster code execution :).

Answer (score 1):

user3561813 just beat me to the full answer, but I would change the `With` line to this:

```
With sh.Rows(1)
```

That way you don't have to assume anything about the width of the first row

Comment: Always best to use rows or columns where possible rather than restricting to a specific range.

Comment: And an improvement!  Thanks, Mark.